# Getting only the Referrer page not complete address in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am using C#. Below is my sample code.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string str = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();   
    Label1.Text = str;  
}
```

The result in **Label1.Text** is **http://localhost:82/data/WebForm1.aspx**.

Now I want the result "**WebForm1.aspx**" in **Label1.Text**

can you please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want only the part after the last `/` in the URL, calling the [`System.IO.Path.GetFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) method on the [`Uri.LocalPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.localpath.aspx) should do the trick:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.UrlReferrer.LocalPath);
```

If you want the output to keep query string information from the URI, use the [`PathAndQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.pathandquery.aspx) property:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks this also worked, just to confirm that if my url contains some querystring then also my result will be WebForm1.aspx or not

Comment: LocalPath will strip that off.

Comment: Answer expanded to include a version that retains the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `LocalPath` property on the `UrlReferrer`:

```
Label1.Text = Request.UrlReferrer.LocalPath;
```

It should provide you with just the filename.

**Edit:** this seems to also include the path, so only works for root.

In which case, you're better off just using `Substring()`:

```
string str = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
Label1.Text = str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

Comment: Thanks! it is giving me /data/WebForm1.aspx, however i want only WebForm1.aspx. Please suggest

Comment: Thanks! what in that case if my url returns http://localhost:82/data/WebForm1.aspx?test="hello". I mean if there is querystring in url did the above logic for substring will work

Comment: It will include the querystring, so then just perform the `Substring()` operation on the `LocalPath` property. I don't think LocalPath contains the querystring.